# How do I use the wireshark I/O graph to plot the value of an arbitrary bit in the data layer?

Tags: wireshark

I have a number of UDP packets that are using a protocol that is not implemented in wireshark. I would like to use the I/O graph to plot the value of the data packet byte at index 3. Is this possible?

I have tried setting up a plot with Y Axis = SUM and Y Field = data[3] however this does not seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried `udp[3]`?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter on your graph and setup with a dot.[image]